# Change header values according to clicked row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, click

I need the ability to populate column header inputs based on the row clicked. I need  to do this using :nth-child or .eq(0) or something dynamic as such because I cannot use hardcoded ids here. I have a fiddle set up to highlight the current row clicked, and the text from that row should also become the value of the header inputs. http://jsfiddle.net/7vLdxddr/1/

**jQuery**

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
                else {
                    $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type='text' /></th>
            <th><input type='text' /></th>
            <th><input type='text' /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>circle</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>orange</td>
            <td>square</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>triangle</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate using for loop this way:

```
for(var i=0; i<$(this).find("td").length; i++)
{
        $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(i).find("input:text").val($(this).find("td").eq(i).text())
}
```

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/7vLdxddr/2/

This is little more readable code:

```
for(var i=0; i<$(this).find("td").length; i++)
{
      var th = $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(i);
      var td =$(this).find("td").eq(i);
      th.find("input:text").val(td.text())
}
```